# Display second query first - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CMS_ORG.GUID, CM_ORG.NAME AS Name
    FROM CMS_ORG 
    UNION
    SELECT CMS_ORG.GUID, CMS_ORG_HISTORY.NAME
    FROM CMS_ORG_HISTORY INNER JOIN CMS_ORG ON CMS_ORG_HISTORY.GUID = CMS_ORG.GUID 
    UNION
    SELECT CMS_SHARE.GUID,CMS_SHARE.NAME
    FROM  CMS_ORG INNER JOIN CMS_SHARE ON CMS_ORG.GUID = CMS_SHARE.GUID 
END
```

Is it possible for me to display the second query as the first output instead of the third query. When I execute the stored procedure, the output of third query displays first then, first query and lastly second. How do I sort it to display accordingly given that the GUID are all equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter and order by it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT CMS_ORG.GUID, CM_ORG.NAME AS Name, 1 as ord
    FROM CMS_ORG 
    UNION
    SELECT CMS_ORG.GUID, CMS_ORG_HISTORY.NAME, 2 as ord
    FROM CMS_ORG_HISTORY INNER JOIN CMS_ORG ON CMS_ORG_HISTORY.GUID = CMS_ORG.GUID 
    UNION
    SELECT CMS_SHARE.GUID,CMS_SHARE.NAME, 3 as ord
    FROM  CMS_ORG INNER JOIN CMS_SHARE ON CMS_ORG.GUID = CMS_SHARE.GUID 
    order by ord
END
```

Just change the numbers in the order you want.